# How to call several organized input files in a shell script loop

Tags: shell-script

I have several input files to run a program, and I organized them in a way that the names of the input files are numbers. I would like to know if it is possible to write a loop to call these different input files, or in others words, to call a input file which name is a variable of the loop.

To be more specific, I created the input files in fortran, which names are "fort.XXX", where the XXX is a number, from 1 to 100.
I call each of this inputs with a command like "program fort.XXX"
Is there a way to create a loop in which I will write a command that is part constant ("program fort.") and part variable ("XXX")?

Many thanks in advance,

Cayo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the names of those existing files you can use something like this:

```
for FILE in fort.*
do
    echo "$FILE"
done
```

It will use all files in the current directory starting from `fort.` regardless of number of files. Of course, you can use any other command in place of `echo`, here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses a range with the bash for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..100}
do
echo "program fort.${i}"
done
```

Which should give you the following output:

```
program fort.1
program fort.2
program fort.3
program fort.4
...
program fort.99
program fort.100
```